# How to find how long it takes for the cash deposits to triple?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck on a homework question and I solved the first part of it where it asked me to find the balance of the account in 5 years. The balance of the account in 5 years is $2208.16. But the second question for this problem has me confused because I'm not sure how to find out how long it will take for the cash deposited to be 3 times at this rate. I'm wondering how to solve this question because I'm not sure how to solve this part. The question that I'm trying to solve is:

> $2000 is deposited with an annual interest rate of 2%, compounded continuously. How long will it take for the money to become 3 times at this rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ F = P e^{r t} = 3 P $

$ e^{0.02 t } = 3$

$ t = 50 \ln(3) = 54.9 years $